# C# Regex Escape Sequences

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a *complete* list of regex escape sequences somewhere? I found [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet), but it was missing `\\` and `\e` for starters. Thus far I have come up with this regex pattern that hopefully matches all the escape sequences:

```
 @"\\([bBdDfnreasStvwWnAZG\\]|x[A-Z0-9]{2}|u[A-Z0-9]{4}|\d{1,3}|k<\w+>)"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alternatively, if you only want to escape a string correctly, you could just depend on [`Regex.Escape()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) which will do the necessary escaping for you.

Hint: There is also a [`Regex.Unescape()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to unescape it.

Comment: Didn't think there was an `Unescape` for some reason.... nevertheless, it won't unescape `\w` and `\k` which I need to do also. However, this will considerably ease escaping everything else... thank you! God... I wish I knew about that 8 hours ago >.<

Comment: @Mark: Next time try "regex unescape" in your favorite search engine :-)

Comment: Yeah, yeah >.< Just didn't think it was possible because of things like `\w`... didn't realize they'd give me partial support.

Answer (score 7):

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) (Regular Expression Language Elements) is a good starting place, with [this subpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e.aspx) specifically about escape sequences.

Comment: Ah....finally, a complete reference. However, it says "\ when followed by a character that is not recognized as an escaped character in this and other tables in this topic, matches that character.", but when I try to put `\y` in a regex, it says that's an unrecognized escape sequence. Why's that?

Comment: Backslash is a c# string escape sequence character. Example: "\n" is string with only a newline character. However, in regex backslash also begins escape sequences. The unrecognised escape sequence is from "\y" not being a c# escape sequence. Using "\\y" will ensure that no escape sequences is attempted when you initialise the string.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget the zillions of possible unicode categories: `\p{Lu}`, `\P{Sm}` etc.

There are too many of these for you to match individually, but I suppose you could use something along the lines of `\\[pP]\{[A-Za-z0-9 \-_]+?\}` (untested).

And there's also the simpler stuff that's missing from your list: `\.`, `\+`, `\*`, `\?` etc etc.

If you're simply trying to unescape an existing regex then you could try [`Regex.Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx). It's not perfect, but it's probably better than anything you or I could knock up in a short space of time.

Comment: Yuck... not looking forward to handling this case. (Thanks)

Comment: Unfortunately not, those will cause "Unrecognized escape sequence" compile errors, and instead needs to be wrapped by a positive character group ex [.][+][*][?]