# Escaping RegEx in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use the following regex in c#

```
<asp:(\w+)\s+.*?id="(\w+)"
```

I cannot seem to store it as a string without corrupting it.

How can I escape the expression and maintain its integrity?

Thanks

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions or even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275904/c-sharp-regex-escape-sequences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string pattern = @"<asp:(\w+)\s+.*?id=""(\w+)""";
```

Comment: Perfect ....  will accept answer when it lets me (in 7 minutes )  :)

Comment: Also known as [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use this Regex.Escape() method.

```
Regex.Escape("<asp:(\w+)\s+.*?id=""(\w+)""");
```